# Woocommerce Conditional Tags in Functions.php

Tags: woocommerce

I have the following code to echo an announcement when a customer visits a specific product category, but I can't get it to work:

```
function gvi_announcement() {
 if ( is_product_category( 'accessories' ) ) {
    echo '<p class="my-alert"><span>This is an accessory</span></p>';
 };
}
add_action ('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'gvi_announcement' , 10);
```

It works fine without the conditional tag, but I've exhausted every other way to make this work using conditions.

UPDATE:
Thanks for your suggestion @Ibrahim, but I still cannot get it to work. Here's my code now:

```
function gvi_announcement() {
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'accessories' );
if ( $terms ) {
echo '<p class="my-alert"><span>This is an accessory</span></p>';
  };
}
add_action ('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'gvi_announcement' , 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `is_product_category` is used to check if the page you are viewing is a product category page or not and the action `woocommerce_single_product_summary` is used on single product page. So the condition will invariably fail.

In a single product page, you will have to use [get_the_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to get the product categories to which the product belongs to. Something like this :

```
global $post;
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

You can then apply your conditions.